# Where to put the SElinux policy generated by audit2allow?

Tags: security, selinux

I'm using CentOS7 minimal. I've installed `acpid` and the daemon is running.

When I hit the power button, I get the following in `/var/log/messages`

```
May  2 18:52:53 localhost systemd-logind: Power key pressed.
May  2 18:52:53 localhost systemd: SELinux policy denies access.
```

and in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`:

```
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1430589539.562:468): pid=815 uid=81 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='avc:  denied  { send_msg } for msgtype=method_call interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get dest=org.freedesktop.systemd1 spid=4177 tpid=1 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tclass=dbus  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=81 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1430589539.571:469): pid=815 uid=81 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='avc:  denied  { send_msg } for msgtype=method_call interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get dest=org.freedesktop.systemd1 spid=4182 tpid=1 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tclass=dbus  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=81 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1430589539.586:470): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { start } for auid=-1 uid=0 gid=0 path="/usr/lib/systemd/system/poweroff.target" scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:power_unit_file_t:s0 tclass=service  exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

Piping that through `audit2why` gives the following output:

```
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1430589539.562:468): pid=815 uid=81 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='avc:  denied  { send_msg } for msgtype=method_call interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get dest=org.freedesktop.systemd1 spid=4177 tpid=1 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tclass=dbus  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=81 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'

        Was caused by:
                Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

                You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.

type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1430589539.571:469): pid=815 uid=81 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='avc:  denied  { send_msg } for msgtype=method_call interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=Get dest=org.freedesktop.systemd1 spid=4182 tpid=1 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tclass=dbus  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=81 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'

        Was caused by:
                Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

                You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.

type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1430589539.586:470): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { start } for auid=-1 uid=0 gid=0 path="/usr/lib/systemd/system/poweroff.target" scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:power_unit_file_t:s0 tclass=service  exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'

        Was caused by:
                Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

                You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.
```

And finally, piping the log to `audit2allow -lar` gives me:

```
require {
        type power_unit_file_t;
        type init_t;
        type apmd_t;
        class dbus send_msg;
        class service start;
}

#============= apmd_t ==============
allow apmd_t init_t:dbus send_msg;
allow apmd_t power_unit_file_t:service start;
```

I'm not sure what to do next. How can I get from the output above to an active SELinux policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`audit2allow`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/audit2why.1.html) can generate policy module directly when `-M <name>` option is used.

This module can then be loaded with `semodule -i <name>.pp`.

The module can also be compiled manually. This is useful when you make modifications to the automatically generated module. Manual page has an example listing the steps:

```
# Compile the module
$ checkmodule -M -m -o local.mod local.te

# Create the package
$ semodule_package -o local.pp -m local.mod

# Load the module into the kernel
$ semodule -i local.pp
```